# How do I allow external connections to my Ubuntu server and its docker containers?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I have an ubuntu server with a few docker containers running using docker-compose.

I mapped the mysql port as 3306:3306 and the adminer as 8080:8080.

It didn't work, but when I tried mapping 80:8080, adminer was working and can connect to the mysql db.

It seems no other ports allow any connections from outside other than the ssh port, http, and https ports.

I tried using ufw allow ..., but even with the rule clearly present upon checking ufw status, it still doesn't allow me to connect from port 8080.

What command am I supposed to run to make this work?

EDIT: this is how the ufw rules look now after I asked the person who started this server to open up the ports for me. Now, the 8080 and 3306 ports work, but the guy didn't tell me anything about what he did. I'm guessing there was some kind of other firewall only he had access to :/

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80:61000/tcp               ALLOW       Anywhere                  
172.17.0.1 8081/tcp        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8081/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80:61000/tcp (v6)          ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8081/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

8080/tcp                   ALLOW FWD   Anywhere                  
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: This sounds like the problem is in the configuration on the connection between the ubuntu server and the external client. Can you elaborate on how the client access the ubuntu server? Another point is if you can access the port 3306 and 8080 from inside the ubuntu server. In addition, what would happen if you run a web server at 8080 port and try to access to it from the external client?

Comment: @KotaMori Adminer on server port 80 mapped to 8080 container port worked just fine and I can access it from a web browser. SSH on port 22 works fine as well. It's only a problem when I try to map 8080:8080 like that. And from what I can tell the adminer (on 80:8080) can connect to the database (3306:3306) just fine, so I think it's safe to assume that the containers can talk to each other inside the server fine. I cannot access anything from the external client(browser,tableplus) unless it's on port 80, 443.

Comment: Some possibilities that comes to my mind are... (1) The ubuntu server does not expose 8080 port to the external client. This could be firewall issues. You could show uwf rules here. (2) Some services limit the access from outside localhost. But this is less likely because you can access if the ports are 80 or 443. In any case, I suggest you describe more details of the network structure in this question, since this situation may happen for many reasons.

Comment: Is the server behind some data center firewall? If it's an AWS instance, check the Security Group (or something similar if other cloud providers)

Comment: It works now, I have shared the ufw rules. Anyway, it seems that there was some kind of firewall only the IT guy of my client had access to. :/ It started working now after I asked that IT guy to open up the ports. So, I guess it's case-closed?

Comment: I am only used to working with Amazon Linux on AWS, so I guess working with a server started by someone else just confused me a bit. Sorry and thank you, for all of your time.